# Ant design Form validateTrigger change dynamically from "onBlur", to "onChange"

Tags: antd

Ant design by default validates errors on 'onChange' event, meaning that the user will get error when typing first time, which is a bad UI experience.

validateTrigger can be changed to 'onBlur', but then it will always validate on blur, which is even worse.

Expected:
User starts typing - error is not shown
User ends typing and blurs - error is shown
From then on, error is shown\hidden, when user is typing.

There is no way to dynamically change validateTrigger from 'onBlur' to 'onChange' via state. I've tried, but it failed.

Example link where, error shows when user is typing:https://codesandbox.io/s/jxqyjy293

Example link of another lib (Formik), where it works properly
https://codesandbox.io/s/lp904qlj1q

My original github issue
https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/12542

Answer (score 1):

## Typescript hooked-based solution

The solution I have developed substantially enhances the user experience. The form initially waits for onBlur event prior to validating with onChange event.

**useImprovedUXValidation .ts**

```
import {useState} from "react";

const createInitialValues = (fields: string[]) => {
    return fields.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        acc[cur] = 'onBlur'
        return acc
    }, {} as {[key: string]: string})
}

export const useImprovedUXValidation = (fields: string[]) => {
    const [validationMode, setValidationMode] = useState<{[key: string]: string}>(createInitialValues(fields));

    const changeValidationMode = (fieldName: string) => {
        setValidationMode(prevState => ({...prevState, [fieldName]: 'onChange'}));
    };

    const onFinishFailed = () => {
        const newValidationMode = Object.keys(validationMode).reduce(
            (obj, curr) => ({...obj, [curr]: 'onChange'}),
            {} as { email: string; password: string; },
        );
        setValidationMode(newValidationMode);
    }

    const onBlur = (fieldName: string) => () => {changeValidationMode(fieldName)}

    return {
        validationMode,
        onFinishFailed,
        onBlur
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
const YourComponent: React.FC = () => {
    const {onFinishFailed, validationMode, onBlur} = useImprovedUXValidation(['email', 'password'])
    
    return <Form onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}>
            <Form.Item name="email" validateTrigger={validationMode.email}>
                <Input onBlur={onBlur('email')}/>
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item name="password" validateTrigger={validationMode.password}>
                <Input.Password onBlur={onBlur('password')}/>
            </Form.Item>
        </Form>
}
```

To further improve it, one could reduce code duplication by implementing a custom `Form.Item` component wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

This type of validation has worked for me:

```
<FormItem
      {...formItemLayout}
      label="E-mail"
      hasFeedback
    >
      {getFieldDecorator('email', {
        rules: [{
          type: 'email', message: 'The input is not valid E-mail!',
        }, {
          required: true, message: 'Please input your E-mail!',
        }],
      })(
        <Input />
      )}
    </FormItem>
```

Source: https://2x.ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-register