# when to use array as validateTrigger in antd form?

Tags: reactjs, antd

in antd Form component there is validateTrigger property that can get a string or array of strings as value.when and why we should use array of strings?

[antd form api](https://ant.design/components/form/#Form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In validateTrigger property you can add string like

`validateTrigger="onBlur"`

or array of string with various input events like

`validateTrigger={["onBlur", "onFocus", "onInput"]}`

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/registration-antd-4-24-2-forked-jon6u7

If you want to add multiple input events then you can add it with string array in `validateTrigger`.

Comment: thank you, can you tell me all of its possible strings?

Comment: @KamranDavar, You can check various HTML event list here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp . Form Events, Mouse Events, Keyboard events should support atleast. Those event names to be in camelcase like `onMouseOver` , `onKeyUp` etc ..,

Answer (score 0):

when you want to validate the fields at the same time their values change
you don't need to submit first to see if your fields been have filled with the right values or not.
you can use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52718050/ant-design-form-validatetrigger-change-dynamically-from-onblur-to-onchange) for more information